# Firebase : php push notification to multiple devics

Tags: php, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

i am using following code to send push notifications to one Android device

```
function send_notification($message, $token){
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'mykey');
     $msg = array
          (
            'body'  =>$message,
            'title' => 'You have a new message ',

          );
    $fields = array
            (
                'to'        => $token, 
                'notification'  => $msg
            );

    $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        echo $result;
        curl_close( $ch );
}
```

i am successfully sending it to one device what if i want to send it to multiple device id's where do i have to loop and what format data would be . Please help

Answer (score 2):

[Docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) show how to specify `registration_ids` for recipients of multicast messages. Replace your `$fields['to']` with a `$fields['registration_ids']` which will be an array of strings containing your recipients' tokens.

Comment: should it be like this 'to'  => [2,3,4,5]

Comment: No @Sikander, it should rather be like this:

```$fields = array(
  'registration_ids' => [2,3,4,5],
  ...
);```

Comment: how ? i mean please clarify

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($TokenArray);$i++){
  send_notification($message, $TokenArray[$i]);
}
```

Comment: would it not add 4 different enteries in firebase admin panel